# Map physical memory address to a user space application in windows

Tags: windows, memory, memory-mapping, virtual-address-space

Is it possible to map a physical memory address to a windows user-space application virtual address to read/write?

EDIT:
I have a system where a real-time operating system is running in parallel with windows. The guest-OS(RTOS) is able to read and write from/to a memory mapped PCIe slave peripheral by mapping the physical address to its virtual memory space.

What i would like to do, is to be able to communicate directly with the PCIe slave device from a windows user space application, but this requires me to map that physical memory address to the user-space virtual memory-space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A device driver can map physical memory into the address space of a user-mode process, but I don't think there's any way to do this without a device driver.

Comment: Hello Harry. Thank you for your time. I have been looking a but closer at device drivers to do that. Is using ZwMapViewOfSection the correct API / path i should look at?

Comment: Sounds unlikely.  My guess would be MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache.

Comment: Please add an answer so i can accept it. Thank you for your help. I will post another question if i run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device drivers can map physical memory into the address space of a user-mode process using [`MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the related functions.  To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do this without a device driver.